# How to get saved photo from external storage and set it to an ImageView

Tags: java, android

**JAVA CODE**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView mTextView;
Button mButton;
ImageView mImageView;
private File imageFile;

private static final int REQUEST_CODE=123;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTextView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.idTextView);
    mButton= (Button) findViewById(R.id.idButton);
    mImageView= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.idImageView);

    Typeface mTypeFace=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/contra-italic.ttf");
    mTextView.setTypeface(mTypeFace);

    //String path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/nabeel.jpg";

   File file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/nabeel.jpg");
    if (file.exists())
    {
        mImageView.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(file));

    }


    Toast.makeText(this,file.getAbsolutePath(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            imageFile= new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),"nabeel.jpg");
            Uri uri=Uri.fromFile(imageFile);

            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY,1);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
            startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode==REQUEST_CODE){

        switch (resultCode){

            case AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK:
                Toast.makeText(this,"File stored at " +imageFile.getAbsolutePath(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case AppCompatActivity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                Toast.makeText(this,"File not stired Properly",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

**Question**

From the above code i can take picture using a button and
saved it to an external storage but i want to show that
image with the ImageView once it has been saved....
tried with

Still not working and not able to show image in the imageview
How can i show the captured image with imageview as soon as
it get saved to the external storage

**Worked with Picasso library**

i have coded somthing like this but still cant make the image visible

```
      File file=new 
      File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
      .getAbsolutePath()+"/nabeel.jpg");
                
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,file.getAbsolutePath(),
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                
    Picasso.with(this).load(file.getAbsolutePath()).into(mImageView);
```

The toast message show the exact path for the image but not displays in the image view how can i make this work

**QUESTION 2**

I have noticed that when i use the below line to get a path i doesn't shows image

```
   preview_Picture_File_directory=
    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
```

But as u used a code to get path and it show the image as well

```
   preview_Picture_File_directory = 
   getExternalFilesDir("images").getAbsolutePath();
```

What is the diffrence between this two????

**QUESTION 3**

As i have noticed that  "**getExternalFilesDir**"  this command will store the file inside the Android/data/packageName/image.jpg, Here the problem is when the app  is unistalled the saved files & images all get deleted.

While in other hand   "**Environment.GetExternalpublicstorageDirectory()**"   this command is stroing images in public directory which i can see in the gallery also and it's not get deleted when the app is uninstalled.My problem is that i can't fetch the image which i have saved in the public directory using this command(Environment.GetExternalpublicstorageDirectory())

**Java code**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


ImageView mImageView;
Button mButton;
File image_file;
String file_path;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mImageView= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.idImageView);
    mButton= (Button) findViewById(R.id.idButton);

    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            file_path=Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getPath();
            image_file=new File(file_path,"nab.jpg");
            Uri uri_file=Uri.fromFile(image_file);

            Intent intent=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,uri_file);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY,1);
            startActivityForResult(intent,1);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode==1){

        switch (resultCode){

            case AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK:



                Uri file=Uri.fromFile(image_file);
                Bitmap b=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getPath());
                mImageView.setImageBitmap(b);

                break;

            case AppCompatActivity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use an image-loading library like Picasso or Glide in your `onActivityResult()` method to load the content into the desired `ImageView`. Note that `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` does not `EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY` and that `Uri.fromFile()` will not work on Android 7.0+ devices for apps with a `targetSdkVersion` of 24 or higher. You will need to use `FileProvider` for those devices -- see [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.10/Camera/FileProvider).

Comment: i have worked with picasso but no use still not able to display the image  see updated question